# Direct group isomorphism, order.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that $\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}\Z_4 \times \Z_4$ is not isomorphic to $\Z_4 \times \Z_2 \times \Z_2$. (Hint: count elements of order 4 in the groups).

Attempt: I have tried to find the order of each pair for $\Z_4 \times \Z_4$.
So, $|(0,1)| = 4$, $|(0,3)| = 4$, $|(1,3)|=4$, $|(3,0)| = 4$, $|(3,1)| = 4$, $|(3,2)| = 4$, $|(3,4)|=4$, are pairs with order $4$. Then if I am not mistaken, all other pairs in $\Z_4 \times \Z_4$ have order $2$.

Can anyone please help for the order of some elements in $\Z_4 \times \Z_2 \times \Z_2$? I think if $\Z_4 \times \Z_4$ has elements of orders $2$ and $4$, then $\Z_4 \times \Z_2 \times \Z_2$ also has to have orders $2$ and $4$ for it to be isomorphic.

Thank you very much.

Comment: sorry, i mistyped

Comment: $(3,4) = (3,0)$ and if you have $(a,b)\in \mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z}_4$ you also got $(b,a)$ so the elements with order 4 are:
$(0,1),(0,3),(1,3),(2,3),(1,2),(1,0),(3,0),(3,1),(3,2),(2,1)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each copy of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ has two elements of order $4$, namely $1$ and $3$. Note that the order of any element $(a, b)$ will be $lcm(|a|, |b|)$.  Hence, we can get $10$ elements of order $4$ in $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$.

$$(1, 0); (0, 1)$$
$$(3, 0); (0, 3)$$
$$(1, 1)$$
$$(3, 3)$$
$$(2, 1); (1, 2)$$
$$(2, 3); (3, 2)$$

Now let's take a look at $\mathbb{Z_4} \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Again, note that the order of any element $(a, b, c)$ will be $lcm(|a|, |b|, |c|)$.  Therefore, the order of any element $(a, b, c)$ will simply be $|a|$.  There are only $8$ ways to pair an order $4$ element with an element from $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.  Thus, there are only $8$ order $4$ elements in this group.

Comment: So we can conclude a bijection is impossible, thus it cant be isomorphic?

Comment: Definitely, since an isomorphism would preserve the orders of the elements.  Thus, two isomorphic groups must have the same numbers of elements of a given order.

Answer (score 0):

It suffice to show $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_4$. However this is quite simple, since no elements in $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ has order $4$, however $1 \in \mathbb Z_4$ clearly has order $4$.

You could also count elements of order $2$ in group $G_1= \mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ directly.